# Why is following graph not complete?

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph with at least two vertices throughout this exercise.
>
> (a) Show that $\kappa(G) = 0 \iff \kappa'(G) = 0$.
>
> (b) For any integers $t,s,m$ with $0 < t \le s \le m$, let $G$ be the graph constructed as follows. Take a disjoint union $K \sqcup K'$ of two copies of $K_{m+1}$ (which we will call the left and right cliques respectively). Let $X = \{x_1, \dots, x_s\}$ be $s$ distinct vertices in the left clique and let $Y = \{y_1, \dots, y_t\}$ be $t$ distinct vertices in the right clique. Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be any surjective/onto function (which is possible as $s \ge t > 0$.) Finally, form $G$ from $K \sqcup K'$ by adding a single edge between $x_j$ and $f(x_j) \in Y$ for all $1 \le j \le s$. Show that $G$ is a simple, connected graph which is not complete. Compute its minimum degree $\delta(G)$.

Let $m=s=t=1$, then each X and Y have only one vertex, and by forming a function $f$ between these two vertices, isn't it going to be just complete $K_{2}$ graph?

Answer (score 1):

The graph $G$ is constructed by beginning with two copies of $K_{m+1}$, not of $K_m$. Since $|X|,|Y| \le m$, there will always be at least one vertex in the left clique that's not in $X$, and at least one vertex in the right clique that's not in $Y$.

So you are right that $K_2$ would be a counterexample, but the language of the problem specifically excludes that case.

Comment: Thanks so much, and How can I find the minimum degree of G? I think this depends on which copies I choose from $K_{m+1}$?

Comment: I think if you draw a relatively large example, such as $t=3, s=4, m=5$, you will get a better idea for what the minimum degree should be, and which vertices achieve the minimum degree. You can then ponder whether such a vertex always exists, or whether it depends on your choice of $X$, $Y$, and $f$.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Can you explain what the copy of graph is? I am just confused by the definition,,,

Comment: Taking "two copies of $K_{m+1}$" means we build a graph with $2m+2$ vertices total. The first $m+1$ vertices are all adjacent to each other, forming a subgraph isomorphic to $K_{m+1}$: this is the "left clique". The last $m+1$ vertices are all adjacent to each other, also forming a subgraph isomorphic to $K_{m+1}$: this is the "right clique".

Comment: Thanks sir, but What I don't understand is that It is said that K(G)=t (vertex connectivity=t), but if we remove t vertices, which are the elements of right clique, all we get is just copy of left clique which is connected? Can you explain why K(G)=t?

Comment: If we remove $t$ vertices from the right clique (the set $Y$), then we're left with all $m+1$ vertices of the left clique, as well as $m+1-t$ remaining vertices of the right clique.

Comment: I now understand.. I was confused that two copies of K_{n+1} have only t,s vertices respectively.